# Sonar Jacoco not considering Kotlin androidTest (integration test case) in coverage

Tags: android, kotlin, sonarqube, integration-testing, jacoco

I have local and integrated test cases written for my android project. Using `Kotlin`(1.4.21) `Robolectric`(4.5.1), `sonar`(2.7.1), `Jacoco`(maven plugin 0.8.2)

The problem is that the `Sonar` and `Jacoco` is not considering `androidTest`(integration test case) written in `Kotlin` for code coverage
However sonar is showing correct coverage for other test cases like-

java unit test cases -> working

koltin unit test case -> working

java integrated test cases -> working

kotlin integrated test cases -> **NOT WORKING**

Although I have checked the paths I have set for sonar and it's all correct.

```
properties['sonar.java.binaries'] = files("${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/universalDebug/classes")
properties["sonar.java.binaries"] += files("${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/universalDebug/")

properties['sonar.java.test.binaries'] = files("${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/universalDebugAndroidTest/classes")
properties['sonar.java.test.binaries'] += files("${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/universalDebugAndroidTest/")
```

I have gone through other stackoverflow questions but didn't find same problem. So, I'm unable to find out the issue why sonar is not showing coverage for my integrated test cases written in Kotlin.

Thanks in Advance

**UPDATE**

within adroidTest folder > I have further 2 packages.

```
MyApplicationTest> src> com > pkgA
                            > pkgB
```

It's considering the Tests files present in pkgA but not the other. I have recently created this pkgB
What could be the possible reason for this? Do I have update some path somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not sonar's fault, it was missing from the code itself.

In `build.gradle` we were setting the package of the first folder only that's why sonar was not considering the Test files under the another package.

Changed from

```
testInstrumentationRunnerArguments 'package': 'com.pkgA'
```

to

```
 testInstrumentationRunnerArguments 'package': 'com'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do the following

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
}
```

Note that there are some issues with Java 11 that might fail your tests so you might want to also exclude `jdk.internal` as follows

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
    excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}
```

Or a little bit verbose option but works:

```
subprojects {
    pluginManager.withPlugin("com.android.library"){
        android.testOptions.unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
                excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
            }
        }
    }
    pluginManager.withPlugin("com.android.application"){
        android.testOptions.unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
                excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
            }
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
}
```

I suggest you also upgrade your jacoco and sonar plugin versions if possible

Comment: I have updated my question a bit, can you please check that and help here

Comment: Is this still happening? If yes, can you share a project with the issue?

Comment: Yes, but I can't share the project. Can you please check the update part in my question that's the current state. When I move pkgB files to pgA then it's showing coverage for those files