# SonarQube showing 0% coverage on UI, after retried same changes showing coverage , it was working fine before not sure what is issue

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

onarQube showing 0% coverage on UI, after retried same changes showing coverage , it was working fine before not sure what is issue , no changes has been done , i want to know which are things i can check to troubleshoot the issue

which things responsible for Sonar to show 0% coverage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SonarQube not picking up Unit Test Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174501/sonarqube-not-picking-up-unit-test-coverage)